# Good books on autoregressive distributed lags (ARDL)

Tags: forecasting, references, ardl

I would like to find a book on ARDl **not** part of a general time series book, but focused on ARDL primarily (I have read books on time series and articles on ARDL already - I want an extensive treatment of the topic). I would prefer it not to deal with cointegration which ARDL does not require (the variables do not have to be integrated of the same order even). I am particularly interested in bound testing; I don't work in economics and there is no certainty at all in my field that there is cointegration. ARDL is nice in not requiring it exist. The books in the duplicate link have little to do with my interest as best I can tell.

Comment: I really want an extensive treatment that handles the bound test. None of the books in that link deal with this. They do deal with cointegration primarily which I am not interested in at all.